# KendoUi Grid not hitting update function

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

I am using the kendo ui grid from telerik  https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/index but I have an issue using the update function it is not firing. I am also using dapper and dapper contrib to help my querys be cleaner.

https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper-contrib

I have tried using the tutorials above and the create function is working but just not the update function.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FuelActivityTrackerDal.Models.ActivityHeader>()
   .Name("grid")
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Filterable(false);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
      columns.Bound(p => p.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
      columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeName);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
      })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:200px" })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
     .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ActivityItemId))
    .PageSize(Model.Count())
    .Read(read => read.Action("Activity_Read", "Activity"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Activity").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
   )
  )
```

The following is to show my model which is the following

```
public class ActivityHeader
{
    public int ActivityCompanyId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; } //(date, null)
    public string Name { get; set; } //(nvarchar(350), null)
    public DateTime ActivityEndDate { get; set; } //(datetime, null)
    public string Description { get; set; } //(nvarchar(max), null)
    public int ActivityItemId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public DateTime HoursLeftOnProject { get; set; } //(time(7), null)
    public string Status { get; set; } //(nchar(10), null)
    public int ActivityType { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } //(date, null)
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } //(nvarchar(50), null)
    public bool isActive { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public bool isArchived { get; set; } //(bit, null)
    public string SOP { get; set; } //(nvarchar(50), null)
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; } //(int, null)
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; } //(nvarchar(301), null)
}
```

This is my modal method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ActivityHeader activity)
 {
   if (activity != null && ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       UpdateActivity(activity);
   }
return Json(new[] { activity }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

My Update Activity call is as follows

```
public bool UpdateActivity(ActivityHeader activityHeader)
{
        return _activityRepo.UpdateActivityHeader(activityHeader);
 }
```

And here i am calling the dapper  contrib update function.

```
public bool UpdateActivityHeader(ActivityHeader activitys)
{
        bool retval = false;

            using (
              IDbConnection conn = Connection)
            {
                 conn.Open();
                 conn.Update(activitys);
                retval = true;
            }          

}
```

The method does not get triggered but no error get produced at all.

To show my project layout to avoid confusion on controllers names
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was the id was pointing to the wrong column once that was fixed it was fine.

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FuelActivityTrackerDal.Models.ActivityHeader>()
     .Name("grid")
     .Columns(columns =>
        {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Filterable(false);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
          columns.Bound(p => p.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeName);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
                                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
          })
         .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
         .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
         .Scrollable()


          .Pageable()
           .Sortable()
           .Filterable() 
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           .Ajax()
           .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
           .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ActivityHeaderId))
           .PageSize(Model.Count())
           .Read(read => read.Action("Activity_Read", "Activity"))
           .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Activity").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))

              )
            )
```

And I marked the code with the following post attribute in my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ActivityHeader activity)
{
            if (activity != null )
            {
                UpdateActivity(activity);
            }

            return Json(new[] { activity }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```